# Multiple overlapped permission submit dialogs issue on Android

Tags: android, permissions

I have an app which needs to access several hardware resources, and so it must grant the different permissions from the user.

In an initial version of the app, my needs were only to record video from camera to storage, so I had a manifest like this:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
```

Please note that the two shown lines were the only code I needed to manage the permissions, because apparently no one of them is tagged as "dangerous", so is not necessary to manage dynamically (at run time) any permission from the user.

Said this, in a new version of the app, the client has asked us for adding audio to captured videos, so we need to add a line to the manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
```

Besides, as accessing the audio recording functionality is considered as "dangerous", manifest lines aren't enough and I have now to manage permissions at run-time, with the aid of a code, in my Activity, like this:

```
...
//permissions
private static final int _MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1001;
private static final String [] _permissions = {
    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
};
...
```

Then I request from user the audio recording permission:

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    requestRecordAudioPermission();
    
    ...
}

...

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    //
    switch (requestCode){
        case _MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions denied to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //
                finish();
            }
    }
}

...

private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, _MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
    }
}
...
```

With all this I get a weird behavior showing the intended permission dialogs, but note that we have all the time other behind (of course I pass from one dialog to next pressing Allow button):

[image]

[image]

[image]

And finally:

[image]

How can I get rid of the annoying underlying "Camera permission required" dialog?

Best regards.

Comment: Buy a different device, I guess. That last screenshot does not appear to be a standard Android permission dialog.

Comment: Well, I don't think a Samsung Tab S4 is not going to be a standard device.

Comment: Device manufacturers change all sorts of things, and Samsung is a significant offender. You will need to narrow down exactly what line of code in your app is triggering that dialog. For example, if it is `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, _MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);`, then Samsung is doing something strange, and it is unlikely that there is much that you can do about it, other than perhaps to not have the `CAMERA` permission in your manifest.

Comment: Same behavior/dialog with Motorola Moto G6 and Redmi Note 9.

Answer (score 0):

The strange dialog was on an embedded Fragment (from a library), which is managing that same dangerous permissions by its own.

Thanks for your time.